# Mapping Ubuntu PostgreSQL-related commands to Mac OS 10.6.6

Tags: macos, postgresql

I just installed PostgreSQL 8.4.7 with EnterpriseDB's one-click installer on Mac OS 10.6.6. I would like to reproduce the following command from Ubuntu:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --createdb --no-createrole --pwprompt --no-superuser [username]
```

but I'm unsure how to do this. An early version using `dscl` and taking care of the `pwprompt` option is

```
dscl -p localhost -create /Users/[username]
```

but I'm at a loss of how to apply the `createdb`, `no-createrole` and `no-superuser` options.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createuser` is about creating users inside the postgresql database, not (directly) to do with your local system users, which is what `dscl` seems to be for.

If your one-click install didn't include the `createuser` commands etc., don't worry: they are just wrappers for invoking administrative SQL commands and their functionality can be performed from psql anyway. For example, the `createuser` system command maps to the `CREATE USER` SQL command: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createuser.html

If you can connect to your newly-installed postgres database using psql (e.g. `psql -U postgres postgres`) then you don't need the other commands.

Comment: Thanks! I had the feeling I was on the wrong path. There was also some confusion over createuser, the use of dscl and the user that each of them operated on.